# Evaluating Block Bootstrap Confidence Interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, bootstrap, likelihood-ratio

I have an estimation that is obtained by using MCMC. In order to calculate the standard error of the estimation, I use Block Bootstrap approach and using this standard error I create a 95% confidence interval.

In order to evaluate the coverage of this confidence interval, I repeat the same simulation experiment 100 times and calculate the estimation for each of them. At the end, I have 100 different estimations. My strategy is to count how many of these estimations falls in the confidence interval that I created using Block Bootstrap Confidence Interval. Let's say 85 of 100 estimations falls in the confidence interval. I would like to perform a statistical test in order to further evaluate if my 95% confidence interval is actually good. If I treat this experiment as a binomial distribution (success if it falls in confidence interval, failure otherwise) I think I can come up with such statistical test.

My questions are whether this way of evaluating the coverage of confidence interval makes sense and what can be a sensible way to perform such statistical test?

Thanks.

Comment: You mention MCMC. Are you doing some kind of Bayesian estimation?

Comment: It is an experiment to sample from mixture of multinormal distributions. My aim is to evaluate the quality of the standard error estimation of Block Bootstrap approach using repeated samples, regardless of the bayesian or frequentist approach